# How to handle a large amount of JSON from a URL

Tags: php, json, api, laravel-5

I use an API that shows a product's information, but I would like to get all of them -- there are over 75,000 products. When I open URL that shows the JSON, my browser just keeps loading.

Can someone me help me to retrieve all of the products as fast as possible using Laravel 5.2?

Comment: retrieving all 75000 products at once is not good idea, you should use pagination, get products in small chunks on each page

Comment: But when the number of products is updated anytime, I scare that when paginate It'll have a little bit change.  And please tell me how to paginate json from an url

Comment: In my experience, it's almost impossible to make a browser process 75,000 products. Even if you send raw pre-processed static HTML it's going to be really slow. Is having all the information available at once a business requirement or just the solution you've figured out? I mean that, if you go back to the design table, you might come with a more appropriate solution (pagination, infinite scroll, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below should be the controller code:

return view('Product.List')->with('Products', $Countries->getData()->Data);
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
But I am not sure if this is correct way to fix this issue. I am reading JsonResponse.
```

Comment: It's so hard to get content of URL. It's can not run "file_get_content()" quickly :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do in your case is using limit and offset in your queries to that server and you could use `lazy load` and `ajax`, `pagination` or other methods to retrieve data from the offset with limit.

This make your program more efficient and fast and on the other hand, you don't confuse your user with a sudden huge amount of data on the screen.

Edit: You could provide more information about the API and the method to access it to get better help.